# Kusto String Difference

Tags: string, azure-data-explorer, kql

I need help with finding difference between 2 strings. For example, difference between the strings outlook and outlooka needs to be "a" or even the number of characters that differ should work fine.

I am okay with converting the strings to array and calculating the set difference as well.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

I am trying to identify homoglyph domains with minor changes.

Comment: Do you have your Python plugin enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query counts each character occurrences in each string and returns the differences.

```
datatable(id:int, str1:string, str2:string)
[
    1   ,"outlook"  ,"outlooka"
   ,2   ,"outlook"  ,"outlok"
   ,3   ,"outlook"  ,"outllooook"
   ,4   ,"outlook"  ,"lookout"
] 
| mv-apply c = extract_all("(.)", strcat(str1, str2)) to typeof(string)
          ,s = array_concat(repeat("1", strlen(str1)), repeat("2", strlen(str2))) to typeof(string) on
 (
      summarize count_diff = countif(s == 2) - countif(s == 1) by c
    | summarize char_diff = make_bag_if(bag_pack(c, count_diff), count_diff != 0)
 )
```

| id | str1 | str2 | char_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | outlook | outlooka | {"a":1} |
| 2 | outlook | outlok | {"o":-1} |
| 3 | outlook | outllooook | {"o":2,"l":1} |
| 4 | outlook | lookout | {} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA21Q0W6EIBB8v8R/2PIECddU26dL/JJLY1bEKxHBIDa1uY/vqqfxUiGwDLM7w1JhpFlazU11MS5K6GNIL7QZd5tB9gAiOV2TE9BIaUnmh2i9b9jujGxOkNlxQvOg3w9pAn5L%20fiXMh0IE/8JyekO7fcZu86OoCAH/RMDqligtZzxV8HmlyuMfOpmaUMIiB7i2Glf860l2IbsSQhDwLFQ3k21QXeaAksXOavdLCeEhJXKnijyODAB78iHr1790LYYzK8G5QcXi8rUNTnPwFAR5DlkAs7PN6mAknpdRO57kS8Mq0aLjS5KvBVUNYUOVcOV3BmJPYCXHN6mPxB/mq2AoQYCAAA=)